# difference between these 3 types of variable assignments

Tags: python, variable-assignment

in Python, it seems I can do any one of the following 3 variable assignments:

```
g = (3, 4, 5)

g = "(3, 4, 5)"

g = 3, 4, 5
```

followed by

```
print(g)
```

and the output is always

```
(3, 4, 5)
```

So, what's the difference between these 3 types of variable assignments?

Comment: 1 and 3 are the same, 2 is completely different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- First one is three-element tuple.
- Second one is some string.
- Third one is same three-element tuple, since in this context parentheses are redundant.

Small code snippet will be enough to prove it:

```
g1 = (3, 4, 5)
g2 = "(3, 4, 5)"
g3 = 3, 4, 5
type(g1)  # <type 'tuple'>
type(g2)  # <type 'str'>
type(g3)  # <type 'tuple'>
g1 == g3  # True
g1 == g2  # False
g2 == g3  # False
g1[0]  # 3, first element of tuple, type: int
g2[0]  # "(", first char of string, type: str
```

To sum up, string representation of object and object properties are two different concepts. There may be multiple objects with same string representation but different behavior.

Comment: Just want to add from a comment that someone had posted and then deleted: doing `print(repr(g))` will produce different results for 2.

Answer (score 1):

Case #1 and #3 both result in a `tuple`, created via an [expression_list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists); which can be enclosed [in parenthesis], as in your Case #1, or unenclosed, as in your Case #3. Some operations in Python allow either syntax (such as defining a new `tuple`, or a `for...in` loop), some require enclosed `expression_list` (such as `if` statements); in any case, the result is a `tuple` object.

Case #2 is clearly a `string` in any language, Python included. :)